# Where is RxJS 6 static merge?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

In RxJS 6, how do I import a static merge function for merging a list of Observables?

I want to be able to do:

```
const merged$ = merge(
    obs1$,
    obs2$,
    obs3$
);
```

I've tried:

`import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';` and

`import { merge } from 'rxjs/operators';`

but neither seems to give me what I want.

Comment: See that example in the doc : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html#example-1-merging-multiple-observables-static-method

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Importing has been made easy in RxJS 6:

```
 import { merge } from 'rxjs';
```

You may want to read the [official migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md).

Another useful resource regarding importing in RxJS 6 is [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCXZhe6KsxQ) by Ben Lesh who is the RxJS lead.

Comment: how to use this with the new pipe operator?

Comment: Link invalid 404

Answer (score 7):

I believe now when the "creation" classes were removed the recommended way is importing directly from `'rxjs'`:

```
import { merge as mergeStatic } from 'rxjs';
```

Previous alpha version of RxJS 6 used to have `'rxjs/create'` file but this has been removed already: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-alpha3-2018-02-06

However this expects you to [use path maps correctly](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-and-treeshaking) otherwise you'll import a lot of things you don't need. If you don't use path maps or the build process hidden from you you can import directly the correct file:

```
import { merge as mergeStatic } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/merge';
```

Answer (score 7):

### RxJS 7.X

In RxJS v7.X the `merge()` method is **deprecated** and will be removed from RxJs v8.X, use `mergeWith()` instead.

See: 
https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeWith 
https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/merge (deprecated)

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

const clicks$ = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(map(() => 'click'));
const mousemoves$ = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove').pipe(map(() => 'mousemove'));
const dblclicks$ = fromEvent(document, 'dblclick').pipe(map(() => 'dblclick'));

mousemoves$.pipe(
  mergeWith(clicks$, dblclicks$),
)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

// result (assuming user interactions)
// "mousemove"
// "mousemove"
// "mousemove"
// "click"
// "click"
// "dblclick"
```

*(example from api docs)*

Answer (score 0):

As of RXJS 6. The merge is in the rxjs/operators

```
import { map, take, merge, switchMap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: Not exactly. There are two merge functions:

from 'rxjs': https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge and
from 'rxjs/operators': https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/merge

Comment: The difference: import { merge } from 'rxjs' -> Creates an output Observable which concurrently emits all values from every given input Observable. || import { merge } from 'rjxs/operators' -> Deprecated in favor of static merge.  You are correct; start using just 'rxjs' https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2394